# How to make an input list?

Tags: python, loops

I want to make a List in python using `input()` and `For`.
basically what I want is this:

```
list = ["Data", "Data2"]
for x in list:
    print(x)
```

But with inputs. How can I make this?

Comment: add `x = input('type x')` inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this;
If your input is end, loop will stop and print all of your input list

```
list = []
while True:
    data = input("what is your data? ")
    if data == "end":
        break
    list.append(data)

for x in list:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Please don't use `list` as a name for one of your variables because you shadow the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). If a variable with a name oif a built-in was used in the question then rename it in your answer and explain why using that name is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I just focused on the question, it would be better detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
data = input('Enter your data separated by space: ')
data_list = data.split(' ')
for i in data_list:
    print(i)
```

By the way, it is not a good idea to name your variables with builtin data structure names. In your question you used list which is a builtin name for python list.